# Calculate a non trivial divider of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

given that: $1683411^{2}=4\mod(2195689)$

calculate a non trivial divider of $2195689$ (without using calculator)

My try:
$$
1683411^{2}=4\,mod(2195689) \\~\\
1683411^{2}-4=0\,mod(2195689) \\~\\
(1683411-2)(1683411+2)=0\,mod(2195689) \\~\\
(1683409)(1683413)=0\,mod(2195689)
$$

and hence :

$(1683409)(1683413)=2195689\cdot k\,\,\,\,$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$)

now I think I should use Euclid's algorithm, but I'm not sure how...

---

edit:

I know $\frac{(1683409)(1683413)}{2195689}=k$

and hence $2195689$ must have common dividers with $1683409$ or $1683413$ am I right?

Comment: Yep, try using Euclidean algorithm on $1683409$ and $2195689$. With a bit of luck, the resulting $\gcd$ will not be $1$, and will therefore be a proper factor of $2195689$.

Comment: (In fact, it can’t be $1$ because otherwise $2195689\mid 1683413$, which is obviously false, so you won’t in fact need any luck!)

Comment: thank you very much!